# Async webpart - the best approach to access outer data source from webpart

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I've already tried to search the web but I always get to some point from which I don't know how to get further.

I have a Visual web part which needs to load data from external sources (different domain). The sources are `.aspx` pages returning `json` and I need to load these data asynchronously.

1) I've tried to use the code below, but it throws an exception:

```
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadData));
Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks()
```

> *This operation requires the page to be asynchronous (**the Async attribute must be set to true**).    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RegisterAsyncTask(PageAsyncTask task)*

and I'm not able to figure out **how** to set this attribute of the `Page` directive from the webpart. Moreover in some articles and blogs I found was written that SP doesn't support it, so I left this idea. But is it possible or not? If yes, how do I set it up?

2) I tried to use jQuery ajax, but it fails and returns no error. I think that the problem can be caused by a **"cross domain"** call. I've found there is *SPRequestExecutor*, but I'm not able to find some useful info on how to use it.

What is the best approach (with some examples please)?
I bet that many SP developers need it, so there must be something.
I prefer the js solution if you could direct me to some relevant information.

Comment: Do you have server access to the other domain? If so, can you set CORS headers? What type of data are you trying to get?

Comment: as I wrote, it's json returned. I can ask the developer of the server side to add CORS, but I'd also like to know how it is with using the PageAsyncTask in Sharepoint. In book Inside Microsoft Sharepoint 2013 it's mentioned (p.347), but there is not mentioned (and I've not beenable to find it even elsewhere) how to modify the Page directive of the hosting page. And for ex. here [link]https://goo.gl/BVqlhm is mentioned that SharePoint's page directive does not accept attribute Async="true", SharePoint’s SPPageParserFilter class blocks some page directive attributes. It confuses me.